# Why are there two public sections in the Unreal Header files

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am currently learning to use the Unreal engine, and wondering why there are two public sections by default in the header file.

Is there a preferred split of what should be in each section? I am currently just copying bottom public content into the top one and deleting the bottom one.  But if there is a best practise I would love to know what it is and where I can read more about it. I checked the coding standards section in the Unreal Documentation but it does not covered this.

So I thought I would ask on here to see what peoples thoughts and recommendations are.

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with "by default"? Anyway, you can organise access modifiers however you like. The only general advice is to try and encapsulate data that definitely doesn't need to be public/protected.

Comment: I imagine this may happen if a developer is adding a new feature and wants all the members related to that feature listed consecutively in the file.